# CAS Authentication disable drupal invitation

Tags: 7, users, redirection

I am using the CAS module to authenticate my users. That is working fine and dandy, but I want CAS to be the only way a user can authenticate. Currently when the user goes to /login, it shows a page where it gives them the redirection notification message, a drupal login invitation message, and a log in button. Only when they click the login button, is CAS authentication conducted. Is there a way to have it so that the only way to authenticate would be using CAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the CAS module but I do know a very generic way to hide / replace any page with another: add an alias! De-aliasing happens before routing. So if CAS has a page say `/cas` you'd like to see when someone visits `/user/login` simply add an alias with a system path of `cas` and alias `user/login`.